# What is wrong with VB str() function?

Tags: vb6

The abnormal behaviuor of the str() or val() functions made my days horrible, the following bug get me 2 days to find it.

```
temp = Val(currentYear)
temp = temp + 1
nextYear = Str(temp)

MsgBox "YY" & currentYear & "YY"
MsgBox "YY" & nextYear & "YY"
```

The initial value of currentYear is "2010"
The result should be:
YY2010YY
YY2011YY

however, the result is:
YY2010YY
YY 2011YY

This bug is gross.After that, I add a line next to my code:

```
temp = Val(currentYear)
temp = temp + 1
nextYear = Str(temp)
nextYear = LTrim(nextYear)
MsgBox "YY" & currentYear & "YY"
MsgBox "YY" & nextYear & "YY"
```

Then the result come as expected. Can anyone explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `CStr` instead.

[`Str`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6a1sx7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) uses a space to indicate it is positive, while `CStr` does not.